# odds ratio for constant as reference group

Tags: logistic

Data: ‎
X1 is a categorical predictor with 2 levels: more than median (X1=1), less ‎than median (X1=0)‎

X2 is another categorical predictor with 2 levels: more than median (X2=1), ‎less than median (X=0)‎

‎(X1 and X2 have interaction)‎

‎       Y: 1=obese, 0=normal.‎

LR:  We use n-1 dummy variables.  ‎
‎     I chose X1=0, X2=0 as the reference bin ‎

New variable:‎
Level 1: (X1=0, X2=0)‎
Level 2: (X1=1, X2=0)‎
Level 3: (X1=0, X2=1)‎
Level 2: (X1=1, X2=1)‎

```
       D1‎ D2 D3‎
```

---

Level 1:     ‎0‎        ‎0‎        ‎0‎

---

Level 2: ‎   ‎1‎        ‎0‎        ‎0‎

---

Level 3: ‎     ‎0‎      ‎1‎        ‎0‎

---

Level 2:‎      ‎0‎      ‎0‎        ‎1‎

---

If the constant is reference, why the table reported the Odds ratio for that. you can see the table I upload it.

[image]

Comment: Add some more details, please, including a snapshot of the output.

Answer (score 3):

The constant is the odds not an odds ratio. If both $x$s are 0 then we expect 1.3 "successes" per "failure". If $x_1=1$ and $x_2=0$ then this odds changes by a ratio of .64. So an odds is the expected number of successes per failure, and an odds ratio is a ratio of odds.